# Using pointers with functions, classes, and stacks

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, stack

```
#include "InventoryBin.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Constants for the menu choices
const int ENTER_ITEM = 1,
  REMOVE_ITEM = 2,
  QUIT = 3;

int choice;      // To hold menu choice

// Function prototypes
void popItem(Stack<InventoryBin> *);
void pushItem(Stack<InventoryBin> *);
int menu();

void main()
{
  // Create a stack object
  Stack<InventoryBin> stack;

  // Use a loop to ask user for input
  do
  {
    menu();
    if (choice != QUIT)
    {
      switch (choice)
      {
        case ENTER_ITEM:
          pushItem(&stack);
          break;
        case REMOVE_ITEM:
          popItem(&stack);
      }
    }
  } while (choice != QUIT);
}
int menu()
{
  // Display menu
  cout << "Please Select\n"
     << ENTER_ITEM << " - Enter an item.\n"
     << REMOVE_ITEM << " - Remove an item.\n"
     << QUIT << " - Quit.\n";
  cin >> choice;

  // Validate
  while (choice < ENTER_ITEM || choice > QUIT)
  {
    cout << "Enter a valid choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
  }
  return choice;
}
void pushItem(Stack<InventoryBin> *stack)
{
  cout << "Enter serial number: ";
  cin >> stack;
  stack->push(stack);
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "Enter manufacture date: ";
  getline(cin, stack);
  stack->push(stack);
  cout << "Enter lot number: ";
  cin >> stack;
  stack->push(stack);
}
```

I'm trying to make pushItem and popItem work. The program creates a stack with a data type of InventoryBin... Without posting InventoryBin do you know what I'm doing wrong? My pushItem function has error codes.

No suitable constructor exist to convert from StackInventoryBin *to InventoryBin

Comment: Some people are irked by this sort of flippant response, but: post your code, and we'll help. Also, on the flip side, people will be more likely to help if you've apparently made an effort to localize the problem yourself, rather than having to carry out a complete code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack->push(stack);` is wrong. Look up `stack::push`. You should be pushing an ITEM on the stack, not a whole stack. The error code says it all: `push()` expects a single `InventoryBin`, but you're passing the whole stack.

And further, I don't know what you would expect to happen if you push a whole stack onto itself....